# Is it actually possible to control stomach muscles to the level done by the Aikido instructor in the 2008 Incredible Hulk movie?

Tags: muscle, stomach

This is about the stomach movements done by the "Aikido instructor" in the "Incredible Hulk" movie from 2008.

A GIF image showing this scene can be found [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sJ0ZgsRo_Qc/UrExZxKzQ9I/AAAAAAAAFBo/5Q5g0qJEkMw/s1600/Hulk-4-400-sg.gif) (the GIF is from [this page](http://www.stickgrappler.net/2013/12/rickson-gracie-in-incredible-hulk-2008.html)).

Is this kind of stomach muscle control actually possible or is this just CGI animation?

Comment: If anyone is unaware, the instructor is Rickson Gracie, who was widely regarded as the best mixed martial artist on the planet during the peak of his athletic career. He is a one-in-a-million athlete, and possess core strength and flexibility that most people would probably not be genetically capable of achieving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What he seems to be doing is a mix of [Kapalabhati breathing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shEhrwqcdAU) and a [stomach vacuum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDx1xfSobG4&t=163s). He's mostly sucking in his stomach in such a way that it flattens. He also sucks in the sides of his stomach while pushing out the abs to make it look like he's controlling his obliques and serratus.